# How Can I Design this below View in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am Developing one application in react-native, actually i have need this type requirement. But i didn't know how to design this view.
How can i cut the borders slant type.

Please see the Image(ref link)
[image]

Comment: Refer this http://browniefed.com/blog/the-shapes-of-react-native/. This will help you to make a view like that.

Answer (score 0):

create image like this frame or border and set in .
what you want to show in this frame set in between.

```
<Image>//Set Image and height,width
<View>
</View>
</Image>
```

Comment: I want to play the video in that view. So i need a view Design not an Image

Comment: pl check answer got-it?

Comment: I know that type but using view Component i want exactly view above like image